# TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, jasmine

Having some scope struggle:
I want to test my shuffle function in controller with Jasmine.
Controller:

```
(function(){
   'use strict';
   angular.module('flickrNgSpaApp').controller('discoverController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http ){

     $scope.shuffle = function(array) {
     var counter = array.length, temp, index;
     while (counter > 0) {
       index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);
       counter--;
       temp = array[counter];
       array[counter] = array[index];
       array[index] = temp;
     }
     return array;
   };
   $scope.shuffled=$scope.shuffle(array);
  ...  
})();
```

and my jasmine test:

```
'use strict';

var scope, $controller, $rootScope;
beforeEach(module('flickrNgSpaApp'));
describe('Controller: discoverController', function () {
  beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_) {
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

  describe('shuffle array of tags', function () {
    it('Should shuffle tags', function () {
      var $scope = {};
      var controller = $controller('discoverController', {
        $scope: $scope
      });
      var tags = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'];
      var shuffledTags = scope.shuffle(tags);
      expect(shuffledTags).not.toEqual(['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']);
    });
  });
```

and I am stuck with TypeError: Cannot read property 'shuffle' of undefined.
Any idea?

Comment: Do you want `var shuffledTags = $scope.shuffle(tags)` in your jasmine test?  You never set the `scope` variable which is defined at the top.

Comment: I'm not an angular developer, so forgive me if I'm off here.  I don't see where you define `scope`.  I see `$scope` being defined, but not `scope`.

Comment: completely true, typo :) but now i get TypeError: Cannot read property 'shuffle' of undefined